# Regular Expression for 2 or more strings, with php

Tags: php, regex

I have strings like this : "ABC/ABC/123", "ABC/ABC/123/567", "ABC/123"

And I want to search the strings that have 2 ore more "/"

How can I do that with regular expression ?

### EDIT

I have found a solution like this:

```
´if($sku1!=$sku2 && preg_match("#^".$sku1."[/]#", $sku2) && substr_count($sku2, '/')==1) {´
```

Any improvement?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I use already a regex like this : 
`if($sku1!=$sku2 && preg_match("#^".$sku1."[/]#", $sku2)) { `
and I want to modify it to take only the variable that have only one "/"

Comment: _Why_ would you do that with regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with adrien: you have every reason **not** to use regex for this, though I'd suggest another solution:

```
$string = 'ABC/ABC/123';
if (count(explode('/',$string)) > 2)
{
    echo $string.' contains at least 2 slashes';
}
```

**EDIT**

As the OP pointed out in his comment below: `substr_count($string,'/')` is the easiest and fastest way to check for 2+ slashes...

Comment: `count(explode('/',$string))` gives slashes number +1 here !

Comment: That's why, to check for **2 or more** slashes, the count must be larger than two... passing 'A/B' won't result in `A/B contains at least 2 slashes`

Comment: ´substr_count($string, '/')´ is simpler in this case ;)

Comment: @Bizboss: true, absolutely true... completely forgot about that one! :-D

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the regex:

```
^([^\/]+\/){2,}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Without regexp (so much faster) :

```
$string = "ABC/ABC/123";

if (strpos($string, '/', strpos($string, '/') + 1) !== FALSE) {
    echo "2 or more slashes in this string!";
}
```